# Google Charts API not working in IE

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to display a graph using Google Charts API:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chd=t:2,5,1,2,69,68,30,178,2,63,10,18,6&chl=Vercelli (2)|Torino+(ex+Pinerolo) (5)|Torino (1)|Milano (2)|Mantova (69)|Ivrea (68)|Genova+(ex+Chiavari) (30)|Genova (178)|Cuneo (2)|Brescia (63)|Bergamo (10)|Asti+(ex+Alba) (18)|Asti (6)&cht=p&chds=0,20&chs=400x200
```

This URL is working in all browsers except IE11. IE is complaining about the security certificate emitted for another site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the more recent URL http://chart.googleapis.com/chart instead, which certificate is trusted by IE (see https://trac-hacks.org/ticket/10279 ).